# Core Data prepareForDeletion woes

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data

I'm interested how prepareForDeletion works.

I have a pretty simple object graph. One class called `Individual` and one class called `Group`. The relationship between them is many-to-many.

What I have done so far is that when I delete a group, I check if the Individuals that belong to the group only belong to the group being deleted, if they are then I delete the individuals as well.

It looks something like this:

**Group.m**

```
- (void)prepareForDeletion {

    //individual check: if this group was the last associated with that individual, delete the individual
    for (Individual *individual in self.individuals) {

        if ([individual.groups count] == 1) {
            [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:individual];
        }
    }
}
```

Now I had the idea to do basically the same approach to `Individual`. That is, when an `Individual` is deleted I check if the `Individual` that is about to get deleted is the last one in the group. If it's the last `Individual` then the group should be deleted as well.

**Individual.m**

```
- (void)prepareForDeletion {

    // Group check: if this individual was the last associated with that group, delete group
    for (Group *group in self.groups) {

        if ([group.individuals count] == 1) {

            [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:group];
        }
    }
}
```

So if I choose the route to delete an Individual that has has only one relationship to one group. Then both the individual and group should be deleted:

```
Individual *individualToDelete = ...
[moc deleteObject:individualToDelete];
```

Now in prepareForDeletion in Individual.m it will delete the group (since it has only one individual)
But now it will go into prepareForDeletion in Group.m and there it will try to delete the group as well? since it has only one individual?

To remedy this should I call save immediately after calling the delete, like:

```
- (void)prepareForDeletion {

    // Group check: if this individual was the last associated with that group, delete group
    for (Group *group in self.groups) {

        if ([group.individuals count] == 1) {

            [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:group];
            [self.managedObjectContext save:nil];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You might need to check if the `Group`/`Individual` you are deleting is not allready deleted using `isDeleted` in addition to your `count == 1` test

Comment: Ah good point. Although I'm wondering if there is any harm in asking Core Data to delete an object that's already been marked for deletion. What I don't want to happen is an infinite recursion to happen in `-prepareForDeletion`